# Guice PrivateModule custom implementation

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Is there a way to provide custom binding in my own Module which will override binding from other nested PrivateModule .

More precisely:

I have a module  with implementation:

```
void configure() {
    binder().install(new PrivateModule() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(IResourceSetProvider.class).to(XtextResourceSetProvider.class);
            bind(XtextResourceSet.class).to(SynchronizedXtextResourceSet.class);
            expose(IResourceSetProvider.class);
        }
    });
}
```

I would like to provide my custom implementation for IResourceSetProvider.class.
This is how I try to make it:

```
void configure(Binder binder) {
    binder.bind(IResourceSetProvider.class).to(ExtXtextResourceSetProvider.class);
    super.configure(binder);
}
```

When the IResourceSetProvider instance is injected it returns all the time XtextResourceSetProvider. Is there any way to implement my module to return ExtXtextResourceSetProvider?

Adam